# How to work with uploaded file using Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have `Optical Character Recognition (OCR)` project. I am generating an `API` using `Django` Framework. The `API` should look like as below:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "title": "PDF Title",
   "input": "input.pdf",
   "output": "output.pdf"
}
```

My `models.py` file as below:

```
from django.db import models
from .create_pdf_output import *

# Create your models here.
class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pdf_input = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/inputs', max_length=200, blank=False)
    pdf_output = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/outputs', max_length=200, blank=True)

    def save(self):
        self.pdf_output = create_pdf_output(self.pdf_input)

        super(Document, self).save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**In `models.py` file I call `create_pdf_file.py` which should perform `OCR` operations on pdf input**

`create_pdf_output.py`

```
import shutil
import cv2
import numpy as np
import img2pdf
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import os


def create_pdf_output(pdf_input):
    pdf = str(pdf_input)
    pdf_name = os.path.splitext(pdf)[0] + "_out.pdf"

    pages = convert_from_path(pdf_input, 500)

    if not os.path.exists('images'):
        os.mkdir('images')

    for ind, page in enumerate(pages):
        page.save(f'images/out{ind}.jpg', 'JPEG')

    for ind, img in enumerate(os.listdir('images')):
        img_rgb = cv2.imread(os.path.join('images', img))
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        template = cv2.imread('templates.jpg', 0)
        w, h = template.shape[::-1]

        res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        threshold = 0.8
        loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
            cropped_image = img_rgb[pt[1]:pt[1]+h, pt[0]:pt[0]+ 4*h]
            blurred = cv2.blur(cropped_image, (50,50))
            img_rgb[pt[1]:pt[1]+h, pt[0]:pt[0]+ 4*h] = blurred

        if not os.path.exists('results'):
            os.mkdir('results')

        cv2.imwrite(f'results/res{ind}.jpg', img_rgb)

    dirname = 'images'

    with open(pdf_name, 'wb') as f:
        imgs = []
        for fname in os.listdir(dirname):
            if not fname.endswith('.jpg'):
                continue
            path = os.path.join(dirname, fname)
            if os.path.isdir(path):
                continue
            imgs.append(path)
        f.write(img2pdf.convert(imgs))

    shutil.rmtree('images')
    shutil.rmtree('results')

    return pdf_name
```

However, since `create_input_output` function takes `FieldFile` as input it generates an error as below.

```
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FieldFile
```

My question is **how can I work with input file, so I can generate output pdf file?**

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
# pdf api
class OcrPDfDataApiView(APIView):
    parser_class = [MultiPartParser,]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if 'data' not in request.data:
            raise ParseError("Empty content")

        filename = "whatever.pdf" # received file name
        file_obj = request.data['data']
        with default_storage.open('tmp/'+filename, 'wb+') as destination:
          for chunk in file_obj.chunks():
              destination.write(chunk)
        dirName = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        cwd = Path.cwd()
        filename = os.path.join(cwd, 'media','tmp','whatever.pdf')
        texts = print_pages(filename)
        return Response(texts)
    
utils.py
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter
import requests
import docx2txt
import pdf2image
import PyPDF2
import pyttsx3
import os
import io
def print_pages(pdf_file):
    images = pdf2image.convert_from_path(pdf_file)
    for pages,img in enumerate(images):

        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
        print(text)
        return text
```

Comment: [edit]ing your answer and adding an explanation of your code will make it much more valuable to everyone and more likely to receive upvotes.